# Pass Record ID into URL and display all associated content related to the ID

Tags: visualforce

I want for a user to click a URL from 1 VF page, which effectively passes the records ID to the next VF page. Then I want to display the associated record's information

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sites}" var="site">
        <apex:outputLink value="/apex/SBLD_Home?id={!site.Name}">
            <apex:column value="{!site.Site_Name__c}"/>
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I get the following error

> Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: pages/Launchpad.page: `<apex:column>` must
>   be the direct child of either `<apex:dataTable>` or
>   `<apex:pageBlockTable>`

Comment: Share your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: It's unlikely that this is correct: `id={!site.Name}`. This line doesn't look like an Id to me.

Answer (score 1):

The error message specifies exactly what you need to change. You need to make the `<apex:column>` tag a direct descendent of your `<apex:pageBlockTable>` tag.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sites}" var="site">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Page.SBLD_Home, null [id=site.Id])}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Note also that the `Name` field is not going to work for you here, you need to actually specify the **`Id`**.

Answer (score 0):

Using class like below to get the id as url parameter and getting list of data :

```
public class testTable{

List<sites__c> opplist{get;set;}
String accId{get;set;}

    public testTable(){

         if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null){
                accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
            }
    String QueryString='Select Name,Type,BillingCity,BillingState,BillingCountry from sites__c where id='+accId;    
    opplist = Database.query(QueryString);
    }
    }
```

To display the list in a different VF page , You can use code snippet like below:

```
<apex:form >

 <div class="slds slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageBlockTable id="pb" value="{!opplist}" var="a" >
 <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
 <apex:column value="{!a.Type}"/>
 <apex:column value="{!a.BillingCity}"/>
 <apex:column value="{!a.BillingState}"/>
 <apex:column value="{!a.BillingCountry}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
  </div>

 </apex:form>
```